# RSpec: Using new allow/expect style for real object

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec2, rspec-rails

In RSpec, I am trying to convert the following view stub in my Rails view spec:

```
view.stub(:current_page?).with(root_url).and_return(true)
```

To use the new allow/expect syntax but the following does not work:

```
allow(view).to receive(:current_page?).with(root_url).and_return(true)
```

However, this gives me a **NoMethodError**:

```
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `allow' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_2::Nested_1::Nested_2:0x007fc7ca971988>
```

The RDocs indicate that allow should accept a double or a real object. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong? Thanks very much!

Here is the source code of the spec:

```
require "spec_helper"

describe 'Navigation Bar' do

  # This needs to be kept synced up with the links in the navigation bar
  KNOWN_LINKS = [:deal_gallery, :list, :login, :logout, :edit_account, :signup,
                 :categories]

  shared_examples "Navigation Bar Link Context" do |params|

    expected_links = params[:expected_links]

    context 'Outside Deal Gallery' do

      before(:each) { render partial: "layouts/navigation", formats: [:html] }

      it_has_only_links_with_ids
      it_has_only_known_links KNOWN_LINKS
      it_has_links expected_links
      it_does_not_have_links KNOWN_LINKS - expected_links

    end

    context 'On Deal Gallery' do

      before(:each) do
        # view.stub(:current_page?).with(root_url).and_return(true)
        allow(view).to receive(:current_page?).with(root_url).and_return(true)
        render partial: "layouts/navigation", formats: [:html]
      end

      it_has_only_links_with_ids
      it_has_only_known_links KNOWN_LINKS
      it_has_link :categories
      it_does_not_have_link :deal_gallery
    end

  end

  context 'For Anonymous User' do

    it_behaves_like "Navigation Bar Link Context",
      expected_links: [:deal_gallery, :login, :signup]

  end

  context 'For Authenticated User' do

    login_user

    it_behaves_like "Navigation Bar Link Context",
      expected_links: [:deal_gallery, :list, :logout, :edit_account]

  end

end
```

Comment: Please share the contents of your spec file.  It's likely this code is appearing outside of an `it` block.

Comment: Sourced code attached. Thanks!

Comment: What version of RSpec are you using?

Comment: I was using 2.13.0. I just upgraded to 2.14.1 and now everything works perfectly. Thanks for your advice!